# ReferenceError: firstName is not defined - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects representing a contact lists. I'm creating a function that takes name and a property as arguments and checks if name is an actual contact's firstName and the given property (prop) is a property of that contact. If both are true, then return the "value" of that property. If name does not correspond to any contacts then return "No such contact". If prop does not correspond to any valid properties of a contact found to match name then it should return "No such property".

Here's the array of objects:

```
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];
```

Here is the code that is returning the error message -- **ReferenceError: firstName is not defined**:

Code:

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop){
    for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        if (contacts[i][firstName] == name) {
            return contacts[i][prop];
        } else {
          return "No such property";
        } 
    }
    return "No such contact";
}
```

Comment: Missing quotes around 'firstName'. Better yet, just do `contacts[i].firstName`.

Comment: replace contacts[i][firstname] with contacts[i].firstName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function lookUpProfile(name, prop){
    for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        if (contacts[i].firstName == name) {
            return contacts[i][prop];
        } else {
          return "No such property";
        } 
    }
    return "No such contact";
}
```

You could have added quotes like `contact[i]['firstName']`, but you can just do `contact[i].firstName`